# Rounding column in attribute table using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I want to use the Field Calculator in ArcMap to round an existing column to two decimals. Currently I have a column that is 6 decimal places long and would like to simply round it down to 2 decimals.

I had planned on using the Field Calculator (possibly using Python) to do this, but maybe there is an easier way?

---

The accepted answer is probably the easiest way to change a single field, however, here is how to do it with the field calculator for both python and VB.

VB:

```
round([column], 2)
```

Python:

```
round(!column!, 2)
```

Comment: An appropriate Field Calculator expression can change the data so that they closely approximate multiples of 0.01.  *How* close depends on how the field is stored; it will differ between floats, doubles, and decimal encoding.  (The first two formats cannot exactly store certain values, such as 0.03 = 1.1000001111010111000010100011110...B, which is a repeating infinite binary expression.)  Do you perhaps intend to change the field itself so that it accurately stores only decimal numbers with two decimal places?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you go to dispay, calculate or label the field you could just use,
round ([my_field],2)
also to change the field behavior in arcmap...
[image: rounding example]

Comment: crisscrossed with your edit.  oops

Comment: It's ok, really liked the field behavior bit of knowledge. For what I am doing that would suffice.

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried something like what's below in the Field Calculator?

```
round(!FieldName!, 2)
```

Make sure you set the Parser to Python in the Field Calculator.

Comment: Yup, that's the python way! Apparently it's the exact same thing as the VB way (if you double click on the field to add it). The only difference is ! vs [].

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like some simple string formatting would do the trick for you:

```
>>> "%.2f" % 3.99999
'4.00'
>>>
```

or, with the number stored in a variable:

```
>>> j = 3.999999
>>> "%.2f" % j
'4.00'
>>>
```

This could easily be wrapped up in a Field Calculator function.