# Decimal place in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, attribute-table, string

In this attribute table, "DISTANCE" field name created with this python expression (in Field Claculator):

```
str( !Shape_Leng! ) + !field_name!
```

[image]

Everything works fine.

But I seek a way to get on 1 number of decimal place and not 9 places as in the result. In the Field Properties the option to change is blocked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps easier to create a new **float** field, set the decimal place to `1` and copy over the values from `!Shape_Leng!`. Then use this in your expression above.

Comment: can you write it as an answer please? i can't understand you.

Comment: You can also use Python function round: str( round(!Shape_Leng!,1) ) + !field_name!

Comment: Also check this post: [Rounding column in attribute table using ArcGIS Field Calculator?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18397/rounding-column-in-attribute-table-using-arcgis-field-calculator)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`'%.1f %s' % (!SHAPE_Leng!, !field_name!)`

`%.1f` represents float with 1 decimal digit. Replace it with `%.2f` to get 2 digits and so on. `%s` is a string.

Or you can use `format()`

[String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) on Python site